Confgure IntelliJ to add blank lines before return statement
Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to automatically insert a blank line before return statement when using CTRL + ALT + L?
Here's how my code looks:
    public static String getValue() {
    String some = "a";
    String another = "bb";
    return some;
}

I would like it to reformat to (CTRL + ALT + L):
    public static String getValue() {
    String some = "a";
    String another = "bb";

    return some;
}


I’m afraid this feature is not natively supported by IntelliJ. Currently, there is no specific setting for "adding a blank line before return statements" under File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Blank Lines.
And  for a method that contains only one line (the return statement), would it look strange to have a blank line before?

@NeverMore: I think only about methods with many lines
